# How can I show context free grammars are strictly more expressive than regular expressions with an example?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I need to show a CFG can express everything that can be expressed by a regular expression, and something that cannot..

I have no idea what example is traditionally used for this.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical example is the language $L=\{a^nb^n\mid n\ge 0\}$. It's easy to produce a CFG for this and it's nearly as easy to show that it's not a regular language. For your first question, note that any regular language can be generated by a left-linear grammar and these are CFGs, so any regular language is also context-free.

Comment: Showing that $L$ isn't regular is only easy if you already know how to do it.

Comment: Could you please provide an example with a CFG and regular expression?

Comment: A CFG for $L$ is given by the productions $S\rightarrow aSb\mid\epsilon$. There's no regular expression denoting that language.